# Word cloud based on each row

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, word-cloud

My data frame looks like -

```
state       text
a         good,abc,bad,good,to
b         oil,reach,bad,oil,and
c         milk,oil,milk,milk
```

I want to do word cloud based on each state. My code is given below -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

def show_wordcloud(data, title):

    wordcloud = WordCloud(
    background_color='white',
    max_words=200,
    max_font_size=40,
    scale=3,
).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')

    if title:
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.savefig('cluster{}.png'.format(title))
    plt.show()


for row in df.iterrows():
    show_wordcloud(row[text], row[State])
```

But not getting any results. Error is -

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-341-c01a0b1ee783> in <module>
     24 
     25 for row in lead_state_wise1.iterrows():
---> 26     show_wordcloud(row[text], row[State])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried? If so, can you post your attempt so we can help debug?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I have just done the word cloud based on whole text not state wise. What I have done is present in the above code.

Comment: Yes - I see that you said that at the top. Please give it a try and we can help you debug. See this guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question on stack overflow. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado - Edited..can you please check it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the edit. Pass in row[text] and row[state] instead of df

Comment: @MichaelDelgado - It's not working...already edited the code once again

Comment: Print `row[text]` and `row[State]` - one of those will give the error. Do you mean e.g. `row[“text”]` and `row[“state”]`?